# How can I add a local image file to a webpage in Chrome OR Firefox?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox

If I add a local image to non-local webpage, for instance by doing something like the following in my dev tools:

```
document.body.html('<img src="file://c:/some/file.png" />')
```

it *should* add my (local) `file.png` file to the page ... but it doesn't, because browsers are nuts about security.

Ok, fine, so the Internet says Chrome requires a special flag to show local content.  That's reasonable enough ... I'll just do:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --allow-file-access-from-files %U
```

According to several different webpages, that was supposed to fix it ... but it doesn't :(  So then I found another page that suggested I use a few other flags with it:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable  --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access %U
```

... but that doesn't work either, because Google apparently hates the idea of anyone daring to use their browser to view a local file on a non-local page!

Similarly with Firefox, there is no command line argument fix, but there are a bunch of about:config flags like `privacy.file_unique_origin` and `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` which are *supposed* to fix the problem when turned off ... but none of them do (or at least, not anymore).

It really *seems* like it's 100% impossible to add a local image file to a page in either Chrome or Firefox unless you install an entire freaking web server to do so.  There *used to be* a bunch of options for both, but all of those options seem to have been removed by both browsers.  **Please**, tell me I am wrong.

Is there any other way to just tell Chrome or Firefox "stop freaking out: I'm the user, I understand the security issues, and I don't care ... so let me see the damn image"?